# DRY: how to get a basic React/Apollo web app and python GraphQL backend API going with minimal duplication?

Tags: reactjs, django, graphql, apollo, ariadne-graphql

I'm an experienced SWE but sort of new to modern web development. I'd like to build a demo/prototype website for a startup idea with minimal time. I'd like to have the frontend tied to a backend DB store up front so it's fully functional. I'd like advice on the best stack to use. I'd like a python backend, and I'm planning on `React` for the frontend, with `GraphQL` (unless this is a dumb idea for a prototype... I'd like to learn about it though.)

I feel like there is a ton of redundancy in terms of data object models. I can make a GraphQL schema (I was thinking of using `ariadne + FastAPI`) but then I still need to build DB tables, or create an object model e.g. in `Django`. And then of course there is all the React code to make forms to edit stuff. My app will require a significant amount of data entry on the website to set up users and lots of metadata. I built a ton of forms etc in React, backed by Apollo client.

Any suggestions -- am I on the right track or is there a quicker way to a prototype?

Are there any tools that autogenerate some of this code? E.g., I expected I could start with a GraphQL schema and there would be a way to auto-extract a reasonable object model like that used in Django. Or conversely, maybe I could build DB tables and auto-gen a basic GraphQL service. If these don't exist it seems like an opportunity, since I'm seeing so much redundancy... and in prototype phase I don't care about keeping the DB and the API totally independent; I'm okay to trash the DB over and over and re-generate until I get to a beta state, etc.